# What can be the reason behind natural disestar?

Tags: practical-islam, disasters

Islamic history says about many generations/tribes/cities which were destroyed with natural disasters, as a punishment of their wrongdoings. Quran brought out various types of stories about theses. It pointed out that when people crossed their limits in wrongdoing, then Allah punished them with natural disasters, and the people who were righteous was rescued. Though it was never said that natural disaster won't happen in random. But it focused about a cause of natural disaster.

(From my personal experience, I'd say, everything really happen for a purpose. But I do know only about my life, not about others not even about the whole world. As we fall sick sometimes and we don't care much about these just because we don't get time to think about these. But when I was sick during a critical(during my final) time and was so sick, even hospitalized for the first time and that made me thoughtful about the reason(I do want to mention that I felt like I was responsible for this, while I was facing various obstacles with life I had a lots of complains about these and used to say why don't I die! and the answer came just after one year later). And later on, 6 months ago I got into an accident, after that I got many advices, suggestions from well wisher to be careful about my movements, how I got into the accident! (but, cant help to say, that day when I was going outside I repeatedly was praying to Allah to protect me from an incident) And that day I broke my leg, first time serious accident in my life and had to stay home for few months. And it helped me from not to face the thing I was afraid of. So, was it an answer, wasn't these things were purposeful? PS: I do know about mine, not about others. Trust me, every wrong thing happened to me, I find a reason behind it that I should care about.)

Today earthquake happened in my country in high scale. And in some other countries (ex-Nepal) many people died. My country is in high risk too. So, according to these thoughts, I was wondering, what is the actual reason behind natural disasters? I didn't know about any Islamic research on it. If there is any, what is the answer? Does disaster can happen just randomly or its an admonition from our creator? To the wrongdoers?

Comment: There is no objective answer to this. This is a reason why some lose their faith, some start questioning, and some call for a reform in Islam (including me - disclaimer). The typical answers to this are "it's god's will and we will never know why he did it" or that "there is always good in everything". I find that hard to believe and apologetic in nature. I don't see the 'good' in wiping out thousands and destroying the livelihood of another thousand. I don't see the 'good' in children dying and starving. And so on and so forth.

Comment: http://quran.com/42/30

Comment: hmm. very thoughtful..Punishment for some warning for others. Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When any calamity falls upon a believer it is due to 2 reasons only

  - Either is is for expiation of his sins
  - Or Allah is testing his/her faith by putting him trials
  - About the natural disasters, they are one of the signs of Allah that how Allah is most powerful.
  - It could be a punishment for the people of that area.
  - It would be that may be their time for death has come and Allah made the disaster as a way to take their lives (as ultimately all of us have to die)
    As Allah says in Quran

> “And We sent not the signs except to warn” [al-Israa’ 17:59]

and

> “We will show them Our Signs in the universe, and in their own selves,
>   until it becomes manifest to them that this (the Qur’aan) is the
>   truth. Is it not sufficient in regard to your Lord that He is a
>   Witness over all things?” [Fussilat 41:53]

and

> Al-Bukhaari narrated in his Saheeh from Jaabir ibn ‘Abd-Allaah (may
>   Allaah be pleased with him) that when the aayah (interpretation of the
>   meaning) “Say: ‘He has power to send torment on you from above” was
>   revealed, the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   said, “A’oodhu bi wajhika (I seek refuge in Your Face”; “or from under
>   your feet”, he said, “A’oodhu bi wajhika (I seek refuge in Your
>   Face).” (Saheeh al-Bukhaari, 5/193).

More details could be found here: http://islamqa.info/en/2593

Comment: Very useful, the link you attached has lots of information. Jazakallah Khair.